# How can I duplicate a Firefox tab including the history with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions

**Problem**

I want to do as much as possible with keyboard shortcuts in Firefox. One operation I still can't do with a keyboard shortcut is *duplicating a tab* while keeping the history.

**What I have figured out so far**

One can hit

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select the address bar and then hit
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the same URL in a new tab.

But that does not retain the original tab's history. Which means I can't hit <kbd>Back</kbd> and go one page back in the tab's history.

I also installed the Customizable Shortcuts add-on. The problem with it was, that there was no operation "Duplicate tab" exposed for which I could have assigned a new keyboard shortcut. So dead end there as well.

**Question**

So the question remains: is there a way to duplicate a tab including it's history with a keyboard shortcut, either with Firefox's built in capabilities or by installing an add-on?

**Current workaround**

Currently, I have the FireGestures add-on installed and use a mouse gesture to invoke the command "Duplicate tab" which duplicates the current tab retaining the history.

**Versions**

- [Firefox 13](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/13.0/system-requirements/)
- [FireGesture 1.6.16](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firegestures/)
- [Customizable Shortcuts 0.5.10](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have installed [Tab Mix Plus v0.3.8.4](http://tmp.garyr.net/) Add-ons on Firefox 9 and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd>   duplicates the current tab with tab's full history.

It should work on Firefox 13 too.

Comment: Can you please link to Tab Mix Plus? I couldn't find it.

Comment: This link is broken and I can't find an extension named "Tab Mix Plus" on https://addons.mozilla.org . Can you fix the link?

Answer (score 7):

Not a full keyboard shortcut, but if you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag the tab to a new position on the tab bar it will duplicate the tab, with history.

[image: FF Drag To Duplicate Tab]

You can also middle-click the refresh button in the current tab.

Comment: OR you can middle-click on the `refresh` button. Less work.

Comment: @VenkatH Nice! Except I hate clicking my mouse's tilting-wheel. ;)  Regardless, that may be  worth it's own answer. :)

Comment: Thank you @VenkatH and @techie007! But touching the mouse is not allowed -- that's just wrong. :-)

Comment: @Lernkurve Get a touch screen and use your finger instead. ;) j/k  Glad you got a workable answer.

Comment: @Lernkurve Agreed. I tried searching, but didn't come across any keyboard short-cut for this.

Answer (score 6):

Not a full keyboard shortcut, but middle-clicking on the `refresh` button next to the url address bar copies the current tab along with its history.

Answer (score 0):

To duplicate tabs, while keeping the history of the previous tabs, you will have to do the following.

- Install the add-on "Tab History Redux".
  It is the add-on that keeps the history of previously opened (browsed through, visited) pages when a link on the current page is opened in a new tab.
- Install the add-on "Duplicate In Tab Context Menu" (although this might not be necessary because the tab can be duplicated using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).
  This add-on enables the option of duplicating a tab by right-clicking the Tab Context Menu, and either clicking "Duplicate Tab", or selecting the keyboard shortcut for "Duplicate Tab" using <kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, if the shortcut activating option is not underlined).