# How to make CTRL+N open a new tab, not a new window in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, browser-tabs

How to make CTRL+N open a duplicate tab (in the current window), not a new window in Firefox? I have Firefox 18.

Comment: I would assume ctrl-t still works

Answer (score 4):

`CTRL+N` is the shortcut for opening a new window, what it seems as you are looking for is `CTRL+T` which will create a new tab.

Comment: This opens a new tab. What I wanted (and what CTRL+N does though in a new window) is to duplicate the page.

Comment: I found the answer here http://superuser.com/questions/434709/how-can-i-duplicate-a-firefox-tab-including-the-history-with-a-keyboard-shortcut Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2):

If you really want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open a new tab, you can use [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) and enable the `Enable Single Window Mode` option. This will also force all popups, etc, to open in the one window.