# How can I duplicate a tab in Firefox by clicking on the tab?

Tags: firefox

I had been able to do this, but I can't remember if an [Add-on](https://superuser.com/a/434714/269574) was necessary? I already know that [middle-clicking on the `refresh` button](https://superuser.com/a/434715/269574) next to the url address bar copies the current tab along with its history.

I'm asking only about clicking on the tab, not other slower ways like right-clicking on a tab then left-clicking "Duplicate Tab."

Comment: If you right-click a tab, Duplicate Tab is one of the context menu options (shortcut key `D`).  I'm pretty sure Duplicate Tab is also a built-in feature having a clickable icon.  If you click on customization, I think it is in the collection of feature icons that are available to drag to the toolbar.  Then you can just click on the icon to duplicate the tab.

Comment: I just checked and it looks like the icon on mine is an extension, not a built-in (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate_tab/).  But according to their info page, the context menu option is built-in.

Answer (score 16):

If you are ok with switching to the tab first, this simple key combination will work wonderfully.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> **or**<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (sets focus to the address bar) then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the address in a new tab.

---

The other solution to duplicate a tab without first opening it is to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> drag the tab to a new spot (granted that switches tabs while you drag it).

[image: animated gif showing the duplication of a tab in Firefox]

Comment: This is the best answer on this topic I've found. Is this behavior different from the right click duplicate tab behavior? I think that actually copies state, right?

Answer (score 8):

Without an extension, there are 2 easy ways to duplicate a tab in Firefox:

1. Right-click a tab, and select **Duplicate Tab**.
2. Ctrl+Drag a tab, and drop it just to the right of itself.  It will automatically duplicate the tab.  This technique also allows you to position the duplicate tab anywhere within your open tabs that you desire.  (Note: If you ctrl+drag a tab downwards, the tab will be *moved* to a new window (as of FF 67).  I view this as a UI bug, as the tab should be *duplicated* to the new window.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the
[list](https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/762043)
of methods of duplicating the current Firefox tab without using an add-on:

> - Ctrl-click or middle-click the Reload button to open the current page in a new tab.
> - Ctrl-click or middle-click items in the history of the Back and Forward buttons to open a page from that list in a new tab.
> - Duplicate a tab with its history by pressing CTRL and dragging the tab to a new position on the tab bar.
> - Dragging a tab in the browser window will detach the tab and move it to a new window, this is called tab tearing.
> - Drag a tab back to the tab bar in the original or another window to undo a detach or move a tab to a specific window. If a window gets
>     empty (you tear off the last tab) then that window will be closed
>     automatically.

Below are two Firefox add-ons that will duplicate current tab when their icon
is clicked:

- [Duplicate tab by Skeletonxf](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate_tab/)
- [Clone the Tab by anonymous Firefox user](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clone-the-tab/)

Answer (score 1):

The better solution in Mac OS is adding a keyboard shortcut for applications. There is no need for adding an extension and no two step process

I have used 'control+g' as shortcut for duplicate tab in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Reason for using control+g is that this combination is not used anywhere as mac os keyboard shortcut Screem shot from my mac

> > [image]
> >     System Preferences-> Keyboard -> App Shortcuts (on left panel) -> Click '+' for adding new app shortcut-> Select 'Google Chrome'